How to use items from a DataFrame as a dropdown in ipywidgets
I have imported ipywidgets in Jupyter Notebooks. I have created a dropdown widget, but I am trying to use items in a column as the dropdown list options.
input_perfume = 'Sola Parfum'
recommendations = pd.DataFrame(name_df.nlargest(6,input_perfume)['Name'])
recommendations = recommendations[recommendations['Name']!=input_perfume]
print("Based on ", input_perfume, " These are your top 5 recommended perfumes: " )
print(recommendations)

As of now, I am only able to change input_perfume manually by typing it in.
However, I want to be able to not have to type it in, and to be able to select each item in a dropdown list.

Please read How do I ask a good question? and update your post based on that. Pay particular attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'. You can include some toy data to give others some examples close to what you are dealing with. Also you may want to check out related questions that have good engagement and answers and compare and contrast them to yours.

And here's some examples that include code that may help you in how to use Pandas and dropdowns with ipywidgets: here, here, here, & here.

next time use ``` or shortcut Ctrl+K to format block of code.

I don't see ipywidgets in your code. Show code with ipywidgets
